# Only NUnit error: Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework'

Tags: entity-framework, nunit, assemblies

I get an error message in NUnit when I try to run a specific test. The error looks like this:

```
ChatProj.Tests.MessageRepositoryTests.Logg_LoggWorking_AssertView:
System.IO.FileLoadException : Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

[Here is a picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zNza8.png)

I've looked at the 2 projects in my solution, and I'm refrencing EF 6.0.0.0 in both. [I've tried to look up the **PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089** and this is what I found in my solution.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zNza8.png#1) It's extra weird because I've no problem debugging or building the webapp, and the other unittests are testing within the same project (same EF version) and not reciving this error [(as you can see in the picture from before)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zNza8.png).

Any idea what could be causing this problem?

**UPDATE**:

I think I figured it out. I was using nuget.org/packages/FakeDbSet which was using a command like : var mockItemList = new InMemoryDbSet { new Message {MessageID = 5000, Name ="Erland", MessageString ="Foo Bar", MessageDate = DateTime.Now} }; which somehow is an old way of faking entity framework code. Can be seen here: i.imgur.com/f6dnJbq.png

Answer (score 1):

First, ensure that the EF DLL is actually getting pulled into the bin folder for the test application.  If it is and the DLL is for EF v6, do you see version redirects for EF in your app.config for the test project?  Something like this?

```
<configuration>
    <!-- Leave the rest of the configuration file alone and just add the runtime area as follows: -->
    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="EntityFramework" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

If not, try pasting that into the app.config.

Sorry, it's hard to fully diagnose without more information.

Comment: I can see the EntityFramework.dll [in my bin/release](http://imgur.com/sXHvw4I,5s1UeHk). As for my app.config [this is how it looks like.](http://imgur.com/sXHvw4I,5s1UeHk#1) I tried to add that code snippet you wrote but that just made it worse.

Comment: @JazzMaster, I'd need to understand what you mean by worse, but I just edited my answer to be clearer as to where the version redirect needs to go.  Perhaps try that?  It's just that the runtime's complaint about the 4.4 version of EF tells me there's something which has a dependency on the older version of EF in your code or referenced by your code.  That needs to be repointed to EF v6 as you mention you're using in the rest of your application.

Comment: Sorry for the diffuse answer. By "worse" I meant that NUnit wouldn't run when i tried to add your old code snippet. [It looked like this](http://imgur.com/zGn2WDl,ZBeAhfa#1). Now I've added the new updated code snippet [like this](http://imgur.com/zGn2WDl,ZBeAhfa#0), but I stil get the same error in NUnit. By the way, how do I check the version of the EntityFramwork.dll file in my bin folder?

Comment: I've tried to search my entire solution for "4.4" but couldn't find anything.

Comment: @JazzMaster, the first example you show illustrates that the dependentAssembly was placed wrong.  My fault.  And it looks like your edit later was correct.  Are you *sure* you're getting the same error in NUnit after the edit and not something else?

Comment: BTW, the "4.4" version comes from the fact that somewhere in your dependencies, you have a .NET 4.0 project which references EF 5.0 (see [this](http://brice-lambson.blogspot.com/2012/10/unicorn-myths-debunked-entity-framework.html)).  If you can stomach it, if it were me, I'd go through and clean out all the EF references and re-install it fresh from NuGet into all projects.  That means "Uninstall-Package EntityFramework" in all projects, then manually remove any lingering references to EntityFramework, then re-install EF 6 using NuGet to all projects.

Comment: I think I figured it out. I was using http://www.nuget.org/packages/FakeDbSet/ which was using a command like : `var mockItemList = new InMemoryDbSet<Message>
    {
        new Message {MessageID = 5000, Name ="Erland", MessageString ="Foo Bar", MessageDate = DateTime.Now}
       
        
    };` which somehow is an old way of faking entity framework code. Can be seen here: http://i.imgur.com/f6dnJbq.png